# Visual Basic InternetSetOption

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, proxy

I have got problem with reloading proxy settings in IE. I want to reload proxy options without restarting IE and Chrome. I've notice that InternetSetOption returns false.

Definitions:

```
Private Declare Auto Function InternetSetOption Lib "wininet.dll" (ByVal hInternet As IntPtr, ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal lpdwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean

Private Const INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH As Long = 37
Private Const INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED As Long = 39
```

And inside function:

```
InternetSetOption(vbNull, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, vbNull, 0)
InternetSetOption(vbNull, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, vbNull, 0)
```

Here is whole function:

```
Public Sub SetProxy() 'ByVal ServerName As String, ByVal port As Integer
    Dim regkey1 As RegistryKey
    regkey1 = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default)
    regkey1.SetValue("ProxyServer", "ftp=10.8.0.1:808;http=10.8.0.1:808;https=10.8.0.1:808;socks=10.8.0.1:1080", RegistryValueKind.Unknown)
    regkey1.SetValue("ProxyEnable", True, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
    regkey1.Close()

    Dim regKey7 As RegistryKey
    regKey7 = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default)


    Dim regKe As Object = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections", True).GetValue("DefaultConnectionSettings")
    If regKe Is Nothing Then
    Else
        regKey7.DeleteValue("DefaultConnectionSettings")
    End If

    Dim regk As Object = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections", True).GetValue("SavedLegacySettings")
    If regk Is Nothing Then
    Else
        regKey7.DeleteValue("SavedLegacySettings")
    End If

    regKey7.Close()

    InternetSetOption(vbNull, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, vbNull, 0)
    InternetSetOption(vbNull, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, vbNull, 0)

    Label1.Text = "Connected to Disa's Proxy Server"
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.Green



End Sub
```

Comment: The first argument of InternetSetOption() cannot be null.  You get one from InternetOpen().  The odds that this will be seen by IE are low.

Comment: @HansPassant So what else I have to do?

Comment: I'm not sure why this wouldn't work for you. I don't know VB. My test was to verify Proxy was disabled in IE. I then manually went into regedit and set

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable to 0x00000001
I then executed the following C# code (which is equivalent to your two InternetSetOption calls):

    InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, 39, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
    InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, 37, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

All while IE was running. I then checked the proxy settings in IE and the proxy was enabled. Can you test these same steps?

Comment: @Pete That's exactly what I am doing, I suppose it's something wrong with function loaded from dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the vbnulls to IntPtr.Zero. This should correct the problem.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace UpdateProxy
    Friend Class Program
        Public Shared Declare Auto Function InternetSetOption Lib "wininet.dll" (hInternet As IntPtr, dwOption As Integer, lpBuffer As IntPtr, dwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean

        Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
            Program.InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, 39, IntPtr.Zero, 0)
            Program.InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, 37, IntPtr.Zero, 0)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

This simple program will update running instances of IE with the proxy settings from the registry.

Comment: Ya, exactly. Thanks and Happy New Year!